# Clojure and NoSQL databases

Tags: mongodb, clojure, couchdb, fleetdb, nosql

I am currently trying to pick between different NoSQL databases for my project. The project is being written in clojure and javascript. I am currently looking at three candidates for storage. What are the relative strengths and weaknesses of MongoDB, FleetDB and CouchDB? Which one is better supported in Clojure? Which one is better supported under Linux? Did I miss a better product (has to be free and OSS)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We were using Clojure + MongoDB, and they worked together very well. Mostly because of JSON data model, provided by MongoDB, that could be easily transformed to/from Clojure internal structures.

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB compared with CouchDB: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Comparing+Mongo+DB+and+Couch+DB

Comment: from the mongo db site I see, just saying :-)

Comment: It is clearly indicated that it is the mongo site.

Answer (score 2):

I think the [property graph data model](http://wiki.github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/defining-a-property-graph) of [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) is a really nice fit to Clojure, see [this wiki page](http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Clojure) for links to more information. Regarding free, Neo4j is released under the [AGPL3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl.html) license, which means it's free to use in open source projects using a compatible license. The commercial backing company [Neo Technology](http://neotechnology.com/product-overview) can provide commercial licenses.

Comment: Why you think Neo4j is better? The clojure support seems not have been updated since last year.

Comment: I didn't claim it was better than something else :-) But from what I've seen graph data + Clojure makes a good fit. The last commit on the bindings was just a week ago here: http://github.com/bobby/clojure-neo4j

Comment: I've been playing with neo4j and clojure and am quite pleased so far.  You'll probably need other types of dbs to go with it.  I'm using postgresql for non-traversal queries.  The [Borneo[(https://github.com/wagjo/borneo) wrapper library is the one to use.  Don't bother if your data doesn't have a natural graph structure to it.  Also, Mad Wombat, I'd advise thinking of your dbs as data structures optimized for particular query types rather than as single-source-of-truth storage mediums.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone seeing this question is looking for a current version of redis-clojure that works with Clojure 1.3, here you go: https://github.com/tavisrudd/redis-clojure

Answer (score 0):

consider also Redis DB.

project page: http://code.google.com/p/redis/

and clojure client library for it: http://github.com/ragnard/redis-clojure/

Comment: What is better or different about Redis?

Comment: sorry, i have no info about other DBs, you mentioned. 

i just added "redis" to your list the DB, which i tried to use with Clojure. 
it runs ok, but there were some problems with build on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB have their own [BSON](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/BSON) (binary JSON) which may give higher performance when shuffling a lot of binary data.

Since it uses javascript internally it would probably be good for the Javascript parts of the project. The dates of clj-time isn't (wasn't?) compatible with MongoDBs date-format though java.util.Date.s are.